# Why doew GCC compiles function overloaded with value, rvalue and lvalue parameter?

Tags: c++

I don't understand why this code compiles:

```
#include <iostream>

class T {
};


void fun(T) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

void fun(const T&) { // Why does this compile?
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

void fun(const T&&) { // Why does this compile?

}


int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

The overloads `T` and `const T&` are always conflicting, so I don't understand why GCC compiles it.
I have readen that like "a parameter of category value can't be overloaded by a parameter of  rvalue or lvalue".

If the overload with `T` and `const T&&` works, does it mean that it will be impossible to pass a rvalue to this function in any way, because any call would be ambiguous ? Or is it a way to disambiguiate the call ?

**GCC Version:** gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)
`__cplusplus = 201103`

Comment: `const T&&` is almost never what you want.  remove the `const` and compile again.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile for me with g++.

Comment: It's not the GCC version - it's simply not compilable code.

Comment: My g++ version compiles it, but call to this function does not compile. The question was about the function implementation itself

Comment: And particulary, the statement "a parameter of category value can't be overloaded by a parameter of category rvalue or lvalue"

Answer (score 2):

The overloads are indeed conflicting (ambiguous) under ordinary overload resolution, but they are still resolvable by explicit means

```
T a;
static_cast<void(*)(T)>(fun)(a);         // calls `T` version
static_cast<void(*)(const T &)>(fun)(a); // calls `const T &` version
```

although I don't immediately see any use case for it.

As for `const T &&` overload - it has some narrow applicability if you for some reason want to prohibit calling your `const T &` function with non-lvalue arguments

```
void fun(const T &) {}
void fun(const T &&) = delete;

int main()
{
  T t;
  fun(t); // OK
  fun(T()); // Error
}
```

See, for example, how it is done for [std::ref, std::cref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref).

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you have defined the type `T` somewhere preceding this code snippet. Otherwise, of course, the code would not compile.

It's not *quite* true that if one overload takes `T` and one takes `const T&`, then overload resolution can never select one of them over the other. For example, if the argument has type `volatile T`, then the overload taking `T` must be selected over the one taking `const T&`. This corner case aside, though, these functions are always *individually* callable by bypassing overload resolution entirely:

```
static_cast<void(*)(T)>(fun)(x);  // calls void fun(T) on x
```

It's not the compiler's job to *prevent* you from declaring functions that pose issues for overload resolution. A good compiler might, perhaps, *warn* you; but then again, I don't think such a warning is necessary, since almost no programmer would write code like this, other than as an experiment.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you. So a function with non-reference parameter can, with ambiguation (resolved by `static_cast`), be overloaded by l- or r-value reference